# Difference in behaviour between javascript click() and user click on a button using JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have a form which, when the button gets clicked by a user, redirects to another page, but when I simulate the click with javascript, the redirect fails. Tha ajax calls are exactly the same (except for the javax.faces.ViewState, but have different results.

The form looks something like:

```
<h:form id="form" onkeypress="trapEnter(event);">
    <h:outputText value="Number" />
    <h:inputText value="#{form.number}" />

    <a4j:commandButton id="act" value="Go" action="#{form.go}" />
</h:form>
```

The javascript function:

```
function trapEnter(evt) {
  // cut out to save space

  if (keycode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('form:act').click()
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

When I enter 3 into the text input box and click Go, the page is redirected as expected to the target returned by #{form.go}.

When I enter 3 into the text input box and press enter, #{form.go} is called correctly but the page is NOT redirected.

In both cases form.go is called correctly and returns the correct value for the redirection. Could anyone tell me why the javascript click() does not work, and if I'm doing something completely wrong, please tell me how to do it right.

I'm using Firefox 3.5 if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just call form.submit()?

Comment: +1 - @Robusto true for this example ... but there might be different scenarios in which we will need that.

Comment: @Robusto: that's not possible in this particular case.

Comment: @BalusC as a matter of interest, why?

Comment: @Robusto: it doesn't seem to work either. When I replace the click() line with
document.forms['form'].submit();

nothing happens.

Comment: @MatthieuF: JSF needs to know which button is been clicked/pressed so that it can associate and execute the action as definied in the button. The button name/value pair itself is namely also been sent as HTTP request parameter. If you use `form.submit()`, then none of them will be sent, so JSF can't associate and execute any action (as you apparently encountered yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out why this didn't work. As far as I know, it still doesn't work.

However, after asking the same question in the [JBoss community forum](http://community.jboss.org/message/532959), there is a different way to achieve this in richfaces:

```
<rich:hotKey selector="#form" key="return" handler="document.getElementById('form:act').click();"/>
```

this is included in the page to which it applies. This works.

Answer (score 2):

The `a4j:commandButton` generates a button element with a bunch of JavaScript to fire an **ajaxical** request. Your functional requirement however ("redirect page") can be as good done with a "plain vanilla" `h:commandButton`. So I would use that instead.

You however don't need to return true or false from the keypress. Rewrite your function as follows:

```
function trapEnter(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('form:act').click();
}
```

That's all (yes, detecting the enter key is browser independent).

Comment: In fact I use a4j:commandButton because I want to take advantage of the a4j:support to display a 'please be patient' indicator, using 

        <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{form.go}" oncomplete="hidePopup();" onsubmit="showPopup();" />

This doesn't work with an h:commandButton

Comment: Well, then stick to `a4j:commandButton` and use the aforementioned function. If that doesn't help either, then I don't know anymore. Maybe a flaw/bug in JSF code. A debugger should tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

return false; prevents from redirection.